# Combinatorica Graph from Edge List

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

Can someone provide an example of a ***Combinatorica***-based graph which uses **ShowGraph** and **Graph** and takes in an explicitly defined list of edges (not some auto-generated graph). I  have not been able to find any documentation which describes the expected input format.

Comment: You can find the input format for the edges and vertices for ``Combinatorica`Graph`` under `More Information` on the page `Combinatorica/ref/Graph` in the documentation center

Comment: Just in case someone wants Heike's link on the web: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/Graph.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two examples:

```
   Needs["Combinatorica`"]
   GraphicsRow[
    {ShowGraph[ 
       g1 = Graph[{{{1, 2}}, {{2, 3}}, {{3, 1}}}, {{{1, 1}}, {{2, 1}}, {{3, 3}}}], 
        VertexNumber -> True], 
     ShowGraph[
      g2 = Graph[
            {{{1, 2}, EdgeLabel -> "lbl1"}, {{2, 3}, EdgeColor -> Green}, 
             {{3, 1}, EdgeLabel -> "(3,1)", EdgeDirection -> True, EdgeLabel -> True, 
                EdgeLabelPosition -> UpperLeft}}, 
           {{{1, 1}, VertexLabel -> True, VertexLabelColor -> Blue, 
   VertexLabelPosition -> LowerRight}, 
             {{2, 1}, VertexNumber -> True, VertexNumberColor -> Orange}, 
             {{3, 3}}}]
    ]}]
```

to get

[image]

EDIT: Before loading `Combinatorica` you can transform the data using:

```
   toCombGrphData[gr_] :=  gr // 
       Sequence @@ {EdgeList[#] /. UndirectedEdge[x__] :> {List[x]}, 
                    List /@ (AbsoluteOptions[#, VertexCoordinates][[2]])} &
```

Update: For `Version 9`, we need to change the part specification above from `[[2]]` to `[[1,2]]` (thanks: @sam84).

Example:

```
  combgrpg = toCombGrphData[CompleteGraph[3]]
```

gives the edge list and vertex coordinates needed as input for `Combinatorica` ``Graph`:

```
  (*  Sequence[{{{1, 2}}, {{1, 3}}, {{2, 3}}}, {{{0.866025, -0.5}}, {{-0.866025, -0.5}}, {{-2.44929*10^-16, 1.}}}] *)
```

Then,

```
  Needs["Combinatorica`"]

  ShowGraph[Graph[combgrph]]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I tried your example in Mathematica 9, but I obtain the following error: Part::partw: Part 2 of {VertexCoordinates->{{-0.866025,-0.5},{0.866025,-0.5},{1.83697*10^-16,1.}}} does not exist. >>

Comment: @sam84, thank you. I will check if i can fix it.

Comment: I fixed it. This function works: toCombGrphData[gr_] := 
 gr // Sequence @@ {EdgeList[#] /. UndirectedEdge[x__] :> {List[x]}, 
     List /@ (AbsoluteOptions[#, VertexCoordinates][[1, 2]])} &

Comment: It is possible to extend the function toCombGrphData so to inclue also edge weights? Thanks

Comment: @sam84, can't recall the `Combinatorica` syntax for using edge weights. If you have simple example handy, perhaps you can post a new question. (Thanks for the fix; I will update the post with the fix.)